# preg_match function for phone numbers

Tags: php, preg-match

I have some troubles matching a phone number with this function

```
return (bool)preg_match( '/^[\-+]?[0-9]+$/', $num);
```

The above function always returns false after stripping brackets `( )` and dash `-` am left with +1234567890

what am i missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Here: https://eval.in/84659

```
$p = '/[\-+]?[0-9]+$/';
$num ='+1234567890';
echo preg_match( $p, $num)."   ";
$num1 ='+1234567890d';
echo preg_match( $p, $num1)."   ";

$num1 ='-1234567890';
echo preg_match( $p, $num1)."   ";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1   0   1
```

Comment: @Smith: Your regular expression is okay. there may be problem in your $num See here: https://eval.in/84673 and http://rubular.com/r/7oXv9co98Z

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some whitespace in the string. Try using [trim](https://www.php.net/trim)

```
return (bool)preg_match( '/^[\-+]?[0-9]+$/', trim($num));
```

Comment: i checked, there is no white space

Answer (score 0):

For North American phone numbers only, you could use this

```
^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$
```